# GraphDB: Importing SnoMed CT to GraphDB

Tags: graphdb, snomed-ct

I would like to load SNoMed CT data onto GraphDB. Can anyone guide to import the data to GraphDB? I have installed GraphDB workbench so far.

Comment: Data import is explained in the GraphDB Quick Start guide. See http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/free/quick-start-guide.html#load-your-data .

Comment: There is https://bioportal.bioontology.org/ontologies which has Snomed CT in it. Owl formated. Keep in mind Snomed is basically for members only. So if you are looking for one of the ontologies other than CT, it probably wont be available because it can only be shown to other members.

Answer (score 1):

Also as I remember the SNOMED has it's own format, which is unsupported by GraphDB.
I've converted it to .owl before import. There's a Perl script attached to the release, which makes the conversion.